# How to parse string to a data type that willl be considered as time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parsing

i have a variable that is string time = 7:00:00 AM. how can i convert this to a data type that will be considered as time so that i could use it to compare to other time with if statement. thank you for reading my silly question

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx). It has a Parse method that accepts a string.

```
string time = "7:00:00 AM";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well since you only need the time portion:

```
String time = "7:00:00 AM";

DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
String timeString = "7:00:00 AM"
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Can also check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx for more info.  Did this without testing it so YMMV as I'm not exactly sure how this will behave without a date component.

Comment: Ran it in a snippet compiler and it seems to apply today's date to the string.  Seems to work though.  Again, YMMV